# Cannot import torch module despite installing Pytorch

Tags: import, module, pytorch, importerror, torch

For some reason, I cannot import torch with my Python scripts despite already downloading the necessary software (my version of Python is 3.8).

I have researched this problem online, including similar questions on this forum, and have followed the suggestions delineated in this guide: https://blog.finxter.com/python-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-torch/

However, none of them work, and thus I'm completely stumped. Could anyone be kind enough to advise on what's causing this error?

Comment: have you used pip or conda to install pytorch? with ```which python``` or```which pip``` you can check if your pip install and python environment match

Comment: Thank you for your reply! To give you some updates, I first used pip3 to install pytorch, but while it downloaded the files it didn't allow importing for some reason. Subsequently, I used conda install, which half-works; for some inexplicable reason, I can import and use torch on my Terminal (I use MacOS), but  trying the same in my Idle script still presents an error. Do you have any idea why that might be the case?